# How to show input and remove it based on select box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two input I need to show one of them based on the select box:

html code:

```
<select id="type-price">
    <option value="">Choose one...</option>
    <option value="numeric">Numeric </option>
    <option value="percentage">Percentage</option>
</select>

<div id="input_type1">
    <input type="text" name="Numeric">
</div>
<div id="input_type2">
    <input type="text" name="Percentage">
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#type-price').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()=== "numeric"){

      $("#input_type1").show();
      $("#input_type2").hide();

    }else if ($(this).val()=== "percentage"){

      $("#input_type1").hide();
      $("#input_type2").show();

    }
});
```

Now it's totally fine like that but my issue I have php request when I show `input_type1` then hide `input_type2` the request pick up second one which is `null` so I need to delete the hide one at all form Dom tree!

Comment: Use `.remove()` https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: You can use `.remove()` in your submit callback to remove an element.

Comment: I'm wondering why you use two Inputs when 1 would suffice.

Comment: Even if you can actually remove, I guess it would be better to have the same logic in your backend, and only get the correct data based on `type-price` value.

Comment: @Twisty no it's not for one suffice first one for( numeric discount ) second for ( percentage discount )

Comment: @Jamel yes, but fro mthe User perspective, they make a selection , the input appears, and they enter a number. You only need 1 field.

Comment: @Jamel  But you're selecting the type in the dropdown.  Just have the one input and make logic decisions based on the selected type, not on the box that the value is in.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte yeah I tried that but What if I remove first one accidentally then back and chose it again it will not show up!

Comment: @Twisty no no my real input has a lot of things but just for make it simple!

Comment: @Jamel  If the above code is not your _actual_ use-case, it's really hard for us to give proper advice.

Comment: @PatrickQ Updated the question!

Comment: You didn't make any changes that negate anything Twisty or I said.  Presumably you are submitting this as a form to PHP.  In your PHP code, you just check the value of the select input, and then based on that value, you know how to treat the value given in a _single_ text input, either as a regular number or as a percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can empty the div which contain the input and you will have only one input in your DOM. On each change of select, it will fill the concerne div by the input html.

Also you'd used wrong selector, the `#` selector is for id and you have used an class in your HTML code.

The JQuery class selector is `.`.

```js
function removeAll() {
  $("#input_type1").html('');
  $("#input_type2").html('');
}

removeAll();

$('#type-price').on('change',function(){
  removeAll();
  if ($(this).val() === "numeric"){
    $("#input_type1").append('<input type="text" value="numeric">');
  } else if ($(this).val() === "percentage"){
    $("#input_type2").append('<input type="text" value="percentage">');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type-price">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose one...</option>
  <option value="numeric">Numeric </option>
  <option value="percentage">Percentage</option>
</select>

<div id="input_type1">
  <input type="text" value="numeric">
</div>
<div id="input_type2">
  <input type="text" value="percentage">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with one field.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#type-price").change(function(e) {
    $(".input-type").fadeIn("slow").find("input").attr("name", $(this).val().toLowerCase());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type-price">
  <option value="">Choose one...</option>
  <option value="numeric">Numeric </option>
  <option value="percentage">Percentage</option>
</select>

<div class="input-type" style="display: none;">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides some syntax problem in your jQuery class selector, Thinking about performance, It's simply better to prevent the (non-visible) input from being sent.
Shorter coding and less dom manipulation.

```js
$('#type-price').on('change',function(){
    $('.input_type1').toggle($(this).val()=="numeric");
    $('.input_type2').toggle($(this).val()=="percentage");
});
//To prevent the non-visible from being posted
//Eithr we check the form using submit handler or the button and prevent the
//from being sent do our stuff then send it...
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
  $('input:hidden').attr('name', '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
<select id="type-price">
    <option value="">Choose one...</option>
    <option value="numeric">Numeric </option>
    <option value="percentage">Percentage</option>
</select>

<div class="input_type1">
    <input name="inp1" type="text" placeholder="1">
</div>
<div class="input_type2">
    <input name="inp2" type="text" placeholder="2">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```